# What is the default font in Chinese environment?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm developing an app of Chinese.
I have to tell the artist the font name to design images, so what's the real name of "System Font"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Heiti SC (STHeitiSC-Light, STHeitiSC-Medium) for simplified chinese and Heiti TC (STHeitiTC-Light, STHeitiTC-Medium) for traditional chinese

Actually you can tell the artist to use whatever fonts he want, you can embed it in your app with the appropriate license

[Edit] Starting from iOS 9

For Hong Kong:
`PingFangHK-Ultralight
PingFangHK-Thin 
PingFangHK-Light
PingFangHK-Regular
PingFangHK-Medium
PingFangHK-Semibold`

For Trad Chinese:
`PingFangTC-Ultralight
PingFangTC-Thin 
PingFangTC-Light
PingFangTC-Regular
PingFangTC-Medium
PingFangTC-Semibold`

For Sim. Chinese:
`PingFangSC-Ultralight
PingFangSC-Thin 
PingFangSC-Light
PingFangSC-Regular
PingFangSC-Medium
PingFangSC-Semibold`

Comment: But the ttf file is too large, more than 10M. So we want to use the font apple supplies. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have internationalized word learning apps in 8 languages, for 8 languages, on iOS, which grew out of my own need for a tool to learn Chinese characters.  I now have a "bi-lingual picture book" (using UIpageViewController) that shows any combination of two languages, using the phone's language as default.

I have settled on using the "system font" on iOS as others gave me warnings and errors during compile -- but now that I am building the picture book in xocde 4.5.2, i think i will try again and use Heiti SC for Chinese.

The "system font" is pretty ugly in Chinese; Heiti SC is great for simplified.  But when i switch my iOS devices to "Chinese" as the default / system language, the font remains the same as the ugly one i get (for CHinese) in English.

I have not heard that the default System font is different on devices sold by country of origin; so if you want Heiti SC in your app, it seems you will need to designate it.

I could attach screen shots, but you can just switch your device's international settings-> language to Chinese to see.

Answer (score -5):

I believe that it's Simplified Chinese.

Comment: Tim, Traditional and Simplified are the classification of the two types of Chinese character sets - think of it like as the names of two different alphabets, like a Cyrillic and Greek alphabets.

Different Chinese fonts may support either or both of the Chinese "alphabets".  iOS, as of this time, only supports 1 font (STHeitiSC) in both Light and Medium strokes, but the font supports both character sets.